# How to print/store non-ASCII characters (unicode?)

Tags: python, unicode

I am reading in a large file of musicians.  Many of these artists have strange characters in their names, as they may be from Germany or some other country with non-ASCII characters.  I want to be able to both store these musician names in a list and print them to the console.

How do I print out these strings with strange characters, that are read in from a text file?

Comment: Are the files utf-8? I don't understand the 'non-standard' in the title.

Comment: Fixed title. This is probably a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me help you help yourself.

First, go read Joel's [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Then, it greatly depends whether you use Python 2 or 3:

- [Python 2 Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html)
- [Python 3 Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/py3k/howto/unicode.html)

Answer (score 0):

just include these two line at the top of your code

1. #!/usr/local/bin/python
2. # coding: latin-1

[go to this link for further details](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/)